# H2 Insert via stored procedure

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to write an H2 stored procedure to insert some values into a table. I'm doing this because in my unit testing environment, I'd rather connect to an in-memory than a real database. Here's what I have (note that I'm doing this in groovy, not java, but I don't think that matters).

```
Sql sql = new Sql(JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "user", "password"))
sql.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE data (key VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,value VARCHAR(1023) )")
sql.execute("CREATE ALIAS insertInto FOR \"com.vanguard.fig.batch.core.StoredProcs.insertInto\"")
sql.execute("CALL insertInto(?,?)", val1, val2)
sql.eachRow("Select * From data") { row ->
                println row             
            }
```

And my procedure is as follows

```
public class StoredProcs {
    void insertInto(java.sql.Connection con, String val1, String val2) throws Exception {
        String resultValue=null;
        Sql sql = new Sql(con)
        sql.executeInsert("Insert Into data VALUES(?, ?)", val1, val2)
    }
}
```

The examples were all fairly confusing and I'm not sure I'm doing this right. Here's the error

```
WARNING: Failed to execute: CALL insertInto(?,?) because: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement:
```

Insert Into data VALUES(?, ?) [90012-193]

Comment: "The examples were all fairly confusing" -> source/url?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of h2 are you using.? 
Looks like h2 has a bug filed for this issue. [GitHub Bug](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/405)

Please upgrade it to the latest version to fix this issue.

PS : I was not able to add this as comment since i need to have 50 reputation to add a comment. Hope this helps